# I can't connect to tcplistener on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, tcp, tcplistener

I need to develop something like a tcp chat in which 2 clients will connect. Everything works on the local network, but after I put it on the host, I can't connect to my tcplistener

```
 public class CarHub
{
    {
        public TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
        public List<ClientObject> clients = new List<ClientObject>();
    }
}
```

Tried to put instead IpAddress.Any ipadress my host. But it didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

 class MyTcpListener
   {
     public static void Main()
     {
      TcpListener server = null;
      try
       {
        // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
        Int32 port = 13000;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.P`enter code here`arse("127.0.0.1");

        // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

        // Start listening for client requests.
        server.Start();

        // Buffer for reading data
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        String data = null;

        // Enter the listening loop.
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

            // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
            // You could also use server.AcceptSocket() here.
            using TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

            data = null;

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            int i;

            // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                // Process the data sent by the client.
                data = data.ToUpper();

                byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                // Send back a response.
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
    }
    finally
    {
        server.Stop();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
    Console.Read();   //Good luck
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already have an implementation, and everything works fine on localhost, but after deploy, my web client cannot connect to tcplistener

Comment: in tcplistener, should I specify the ip address of my host as the ip address?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**